# How Can I show Grid line after certain item in DATA GRID

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

I want to draw a horizontal grid line after certain item based on one column value.If I say GridLineVisibility="Horizontal", then all the lines are shown. but I want to show this line only when certain value in a column satisfies the condition

For example here is the datagrid

```
Name      ID
XYZ        1
ABC        2
WER        4  
VGF        2
```

I want to show the grid line if the ID=2?  How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that is possible through the API directly. Here are some possible ideas:

1. Can you use the row details to 'draw' the line by making it just a few pixels high? It would require that you set the selection yourself and prevent the user from changing it (not sure if that's acceptable in your case).
2. Change to cell templates to show a dark area at the bottom for the item in question.
3. Modify the DataGrid source code and add your feature to the control directly.
4. Switch to a Grid control, but then you loose some of the nice features of the DataGrid.

I would do either #1 or #2 if they fit within your constraints.